# Downloading and Extracting a zip file in Python

Tags: python, github, urllib, zip

I know there are a number of ways you can download a file from the web. However, none of them seem to work for me.

Trying to download a zip file from github.

This is what i am trying:
(You can use the same github link as in the code, its a valid one)

```
import urllib.request
from zipfile import ZipFile

urllib.request.urlretrieve("https://github.com/jatinshetty26/pickup/blob/master/testDown.zip", "test1.zip")

with ZipFile('test1.zip', 'r') as zipObj:
     zipObj.extractall()
```

This kinda downloads an invalid or empty zip, which i cannot even manually exact. And the python ZipFile library throws the below error.

```
 raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
```

Any help is truly appreciated. This has been bothering me for whole for yesterday!

Thanks,
Rob

Comment: I suspect that if you right-click the zip file and choose "open in Notepad", it will display valid HTML corresponding to Github's file explorer page. What happens if you try to urlretrieve `"https://github.com/jatinshetty26/pickup/raw/master/testDown.zip"` instead?

Comment: @Kevin Thank you. I knew i tried using `raw`, but the last time i tried it i might have had some other variable set incorrectly. This worked. I feel stupid :D